# Is Ctrl+C on make check safe?

Tags: software-installation, compiling, kill

I am installing GNU Guile and I have ran `./configure` ... as well as `make`. I am now running `make check` and it is taking a really really long time. If I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to abort this `make check`, will it mess anything up and mess up the install, or is this safe to do since this is just for testing purposes?

Answer (score 2):

It should be fine; it might leave the tests and test components in an indeterminate state, but the actual application shouldn't be affected.

That's not a hard and fast rule and I'm not familiar with `guile` but it would be pretty weird if the build depended on completing `make check`, or if the check could potentially damage something.

However, if by "taking a really really long time" you mean it appears to have stalled at some point, that may not be a good sign.  Letting the check complete is probably a good idea, even if it takes an hour or so.